# Low Side Parallel MOSFET Drive

Tags: mosfet, analog, opto-isolator

I'm doing a 12V to 230V push pull inverter design & need to drive it via two MOSFETs for each transformer tapping. Mosfets feeds by an optocoupler PC817. The frequency is 50Hz coming from a PIC microcontroller. Going to do as below.
[image]

Am I driving it correctly? Any improvements?

Thanks

Comment: Missing individual gate resistors!

Comment: Yet again in MOSFET designs, gate capacitance ignored.

Comment: Closed too quick. At any rate this link may be helpful: https://www.homemade-circuits.com/how-to-design-inverter-basic-circuit/  The optocoupler isn’t necessary, you need good push-pull gate drive to deal with gate capacitance. You could also consider using NPNs instead of FETs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You probably want a push pull or totem pole method between OC1 and
   your power MOSFETs. Direct opto drive might be insufficient for PWM
   at 50Hz, It certainly would be in
2. I would omit OC1 and only have the aformentioned totem pole or push-pull driver. The opto does little and there aren't safety issues because the
   transformer is low V on your primary.
   sufficient at 1kHz+.
3. 50Hz square wave would saturate your transformer I think because the
   DC level is applied for too long.
4. You might want some form of snubbing to protect T1 and T2 from excessive voltage spikes.
5. The voltage labels at your transformer primary are incorrect.

Comment: It seems there was an unintended cut/paste between items 1 and 2

Answer (score 3):

This topology will not work for several reasons:

1. It has no back EMF diode clamp
2. The driver impedance is not low in the off state and even with diodes is not sufficiently low compared to this FET to regulate voltage with a load transformed (divided by) \$R_{load}/N^2\$.   The ratio of source to load impedance determines the "% voltage *load regulation error*"   This is critical to your understanding of boost converters and means the source impedance must be very low *(in both hi and lo voltage* states).
3. The primary current should be symmetrical to improve power quality , reduce EMI and load resonance, eliminate DC, and preferably [sine wave](https://www.edaboard.com/attachments/12v-220v-gif.62924/) or 3 level switches.

Complexity of AC inverters is far greater than this and you might study how it is done before trying to DIY.  A DC powered centre tap and dual Nch end coil low-side switches with BEMF clamping is a better topology. https://www.edaboard.com/attachments/12v-220v-gif.62924/